# Run Spring-boot's main using IDE

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot application that needs to:

- Be deployable as a war in a servlet container
- Be runnable via `mvn spring-boot:run``

I'd also like to be able to run this application in my IDE (Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA Community) by right clicking on the `main` and running it.

Here are the interesting parts of my pom.xml (Note that I do not inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent pom):

```
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Here's my `SpringBootServletInitializer`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.company.theproject")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application)
    {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

When running the main inside an IDE I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:183) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:156) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Seems like `mvn spring-boot:run` does some more magic that does not happen when running the `main` directly.

Removing the `provided` scope from the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency fixes this issue but causes trouble when the war is run inside a servlet container.

Right now the only "fix" I've found is to run `mvn spring-boot:run` within IntelliJ IDEA instead of running the main directly. While this is an acceptable workaround, I'd still like to know why this doesn't work and if it can be fixed.

Comment: also to mention: running `mvn spring-boot:run` does not trigger the debugger (when clicking on the debug icon, it still uses the same mvn command, thus starts the app the same way as clicking on the run icon)

Comment: I would add that making spring-boot-starter-tomcat a compile/runtime dependency (rather than provided) *may* cause trouble.  It depends on how the container is configured.  If there's a security manager involved it may just ignore your copy of the library ... or it may except out because you're trying to override it ... or it may use yours and be OK.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe this could be related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107048

IntelliJ IDEA is not injecting the `provided` dependencies into the CLASSPATH and as Andy stated this is why spring is unable to create the embedded servlet container.

They have a feature request since 2005 about this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-99

Workarounds mentioned in the comments includes having a fake module  with the necessary libs and using it as classpath, using the -Xbootclasspath JVM argument or using custom maven profiles for running (`compiled`) vs building (`provided`).

Comment: Please would you mind expanding on how you go about implementing a solution in IntelliJ?  What's the simplest way of getting this to work please?

Comment: @John, I wrote a solution based on the workaround mentioned above. See below.

Comment: It looks like Intellij IDEA 2018.1 fixes this.

> There is a new Include dependencies with “Provided” scope option for the Application and Spring Boot configurations in the Run/Debug Configurations dialog. This new feature allows you to add “provided” dependencies to the classpath when needed. Please note that the Include dependencies with “Provided” scope option is enabled by default for the Spring Boot applications.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/02/intellij-idea-2018-1-public-preview/

Answer (score 26):

A workaround that is strongly inspired from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140041 is to start your main class with the test classpath (which includes the embedded servlet.)

### Steps (IntelliJ 16):

1. `Run` -> `Edit Configurations` -> `Add new configuration` -> Pick `Application` type.
2. Set `Main class` to `<your.main.class>`
3. Set `Use classpath of module` to `<*>_test` (the test module!)
4. `Ok` and `Run` it!

Comment: I don't have a _test module.

Comment: yop83 or @Thirdman can you share how you get that test module?

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem using IntelliJ 2018.
Initially, Make sure that you have added the maven library for the spring project in your IntelliJ.

My solution is:

1. Go to `Run` -> `Edit Configurations`.
2. Select `Application` && choose your current project.
3. Check `Include dependencies with "Provided" scope`.
4. `OK` -> `RUN`

Comment: Thanks; that was a time saver!

Answer (score 7):

I was able to make this work by changing the scope of the spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency to "compile" under Project structure->Dependencies tab. This doesn't effect pom.xml but allows this dependencies to be available to spring boot run configuration

[Click here for image on where to change this setting in idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca2cP.png)

Comment: I could not get this solution to work in Intellij IDEA 2017.2

Comment: @phn: this works for me on 2017.2, I had to set spring-boot-starter-tomcat, tomcat-embed-core, tomcat-embed-el and tomcat-embed-websocket to compile as discribed. try searching for other "provided" dependencies, which may be also missing but are dependencies of spring-boot-starter-tomcat.

Answer (score 3):

`mvn spring-boot:run` includes `provided` dependencies when it's creating the classpath. It sounds like IntelliJ IDEA does not. Without Tomcat on the classpath, Spring Boot's unable to create an embedded servlet container which causes the exception you're seeing. Arguably this is a bug in IntelliJ as, if there's no container to provide the dependency, then it really needs to be on the classpath.

You may be able to fix the problem by overriding the default classpath that IntelliJ uses when running the main method to include the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. On the top right side of intellij window, click the drop down and select edit configuration and a new window will open.
2. In this window, on top left side, click "+" button and select sprint boot.

[image]

3. Then add you main class, and other details as shown in screenshot.
   [image]
4. Now Run the application.

Comment: This is only available in IDEA Ultimate (the OP did ask for Eclipse or IDEA Community).

Answer (score 1):

I find this [page](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206841265-Running-a-fat-spring-boot-war-as-an-application), and use the maven profile to manage the profiles.

```
    <profiles>
              <profile>
                   <id>PROD</id>
                   <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                             <scope>provided</scope>
                        </dependency>
                   </dependencies>
              </profile>
<profile>
                   <id>DEV</id>
                   <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                             <scope>TEST</scope>
                        </dependency>
                   </dependencies>
              </profile>
         </profiles>
```

and config the main class `beforeLanuce`,set the command

```
mvn clean compile -Pdev
```

Comment: This also works in Intellij maven plugin -> on the right side check the "Profiles"

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this problem in Intellij IDEA 2017.2 by adding the provided libaray (spring-boot-starter-tomcat) to the project configuration.

Select File -> Project Structure. Select Libraries and add a new project library (type = From Maven...). Search for spring-boot-starter-tomcat using the dialog, select the correct version and add it by clicking on OK. The library is added to the list of external libraries.

The disadvantage is that if the Spring Boot version is changed then you will have to remember to delete this library and add the new version.

Answer (score 1):

Using the profile and instructions below, you can add a profile to maven that allows development in IntelliJ without changing things for other environments.

```
<!-- Leave original dependency as-is -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <!-- Enable this profile to run in IntelliJ. IntelliJ excludes provided dependencies from compile by default. -->
    <profile>
        <id>intellij</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Click the **Maven Projects** button on the right side of IntelliJ, and under **Profiles**, select `intellij`.