# Spring Boot Maven provided scope are included in WAR but not IDE runtime

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I spent the weekend trying to figure out why a simple `Spring Boot` project worked command-line, but not through my `IntelliJ 15.0.2 IDE` and finally narrowed it to the following:

1. I am using embedded Tomcat
2. The default dependencies were as follows:

   ```
   <dependencies>
     ...
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
       <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```

   3. [Maven provided scope dependencies are included in the packaged JAR/WAR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/413)
   4. IntelliJ excludes `provided` scope from runtime classpath.

So the command-line built WAR file contains the provided scope JARs for embedded Tomcat, but the instance running through IntelliJ IDEA do not.

Has anyone run across this before?

What is the best approach to resolve it?

I can change `scope` to `compile`, but this felt like a hack.  Is this the only fix?

Comment: Why are the dependencies provided anyway if you want to run it from the command line? They should only be provided if you intend to create a war file for deployment on a server, if you want to run it from the command line they should be provided (the Spring Boot plugin moves them to a separate directory in the jar/war so that when run from the command line the jars are still available).

Comment: @M.Deinum My intention is to eventually deploy the WAR file standalone on a server, thus provided scope.  It does run command-line as you said, since Spring Boot plugin is putting them in a separate directory.  However, my IDE (IntelliJ) cannot see provided scope dependencies.  Trying to figure out a way to run through IDE for debugging purposes while I code, and do it in the cleanest way possible.

Comment: Have you enabled the Spring Boot feature in Intellij?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Spring-boot's main using IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237768/run-spring-boots-main-using-ide)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I fixed this my commenting out the scope.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
</dependency>
```