# Spring Boot JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Is there any simple way to generate Spring Boot Mvc project for .jsp views?

I've tried to create project in similar way like Spring Boot Rest project, but it's not soo easy for me. I've tried to use [official Spring Boot Mvc jsp sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp), but when I try to run this I get exception like this:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [sample.jsp.SampleWebJspApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:187) ~[spring-context-4.3.0.BUILD-20160427.201731-353.jar:4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321) ~[spring-context-4.3.0.BUILD-20160427.201731-353.jar:4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.3.0.BUILD-20160427.201731-353.jar:4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.3.0.BUILD-20160427.201731-353.jar:4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.3.0.BUILD-20160427.201731-353.jar:4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681) ~[spring-context-4.3.0.BUILD-20160427.201731-353.jar:4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523) ~[spring-context-4.3.0.BUILD-20160427.201731-353.jar:4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:765) [spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-20160427.203128-289.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-20160427.203128-289.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-20160427.203128-289.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1182) [spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-20160427.203128-289.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1171) [spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-20160427.203128-289.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at sample.jsp.SampleWebJspApplication.main(SampleWebJspApplication.java:33) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:163) ~[spring-core-4.3.0.BUILD-20160427.201731-353.jar:4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300) ~[spring-context-4.3.0.BUILD-20160427.201731-353.jar:4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:237) ~[spring-context-4.3.0.BUILD-20160427.201731-353.jar:4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:204) ~[spring-context-4.3.0.BUILD-20160427.201731-353.jar:4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:173) ~[spring-context-4.3.0.BUILD-20160427.201731-353.jar:4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:152) ~[spring-core-4.3.0.BUILD-20160427.201731-353.jar:4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Try to find which jar does `ServletContext` located in and try to import it and run again.

Comment: Maybe cause the jar was broken during its' downloading.

Comment: Go and find it then try to open it by zip or other uncompress tool and make sure it is fully downloaded.

Comment: Try to check your local repository and make sure it is ok.But first you need locate where it is.

Answer (score 3):

This blog [post](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-jsps-in-executable-jars-1) explains what steps you should take and why. Its fairly easy and I've fixed it myself.

TD:LR

**Add Maven Dependencies**

In order to enable JSP support, we need to add a few dependencies to our new project in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
 <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
 <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Place the JSP templates under src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp/

Answer (score 2):

As I know, the spring boot default page technology is thymeleaf and the official recommends us to use it. 
If you want to use jsp, you could do some configuration.

The following steps may be useful.

```
1. Creating  src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp folder.
2. Modify application.properties file.

spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

3.Add jar support for jsp. You could add the followings maven repository to your project pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Hope it helps. Any concerns, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I don't want to learn yet another template language! And it's even more typing! If they had [HAML](http://haml.info), I would totally go for that!

Answer (score 2):

Add below dependencies to your POM file:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Create below structure 
/src/main/***resources/META-INF/resources***

Now the above folder is equivalent to your WebContent folder. Inside this you can put your static contents. Add ***WEB-INF*** folder here and now you can place your JSP files like any other web project.

In your application.properties file add below:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/

spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you're running in IntelliJ? I've noticed this issue as well and the solution is to remove the `<scope>provided</scope>` from the spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency, like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
</dependency>
```

There's a bug in IntelliJ, causing it not to add provided dependencies to the classpath when running locally.

EDIT: Removing the provided scope might cause issues when you're going to run it within a servlet container, so be cautious about that, an explanation about how to fix that could be found in [Run Spring-boot's main using IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237768/run-spring-boots-main-using-ide).

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar problems, see the link to github.
jsf-spring-boot-2.1.6 parent use spring boot 1.4.0
everything has worked and there is no problems, believe it or not!

https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces-example-war

Answer (score 1):

Adding dependency in POM file below

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Full code avaliable on github link click [here](https://github.com/chandrakumar001/Spring-Boot-JSP)

Download the code and import the eclipse/STS using exiting maven project

Next to run the project.
Go to the package on com.chandrakumar.test.demo.

it has "DemoApplication.java" and right click the mouse and select **run as** 
choose the java application.

The browser address bar type `"http://localhost:8080/"`.

Answer (score 1):

Following johnny's reply, I actually wasn't aware that JSP files could be ran while deploying the application as a JAR. Though apparently there are some extensions that I haven't heard of... Typically, a JSP application is deployed as a WAR, and all JSP-related files are located in the webapp/WEB-INF/ folder. You may need to add `<packaging>war</packaging>` to your POM if if you are comfortable packaging your application as a WAR. This doesn't sound like a bad idea if your application is not a microservice or does not utilize cloud-based technologies. But the majority of cloud-based technologies (excluding cloud-foundry and maybe some others) only support JAR packaging. In that case, you may want to use alternative templates such as Thymeleaf or FreeMarker, over JSP, if you decide to go the JAR route.

Answer (score 0):

Use a maven run configuration with `spring-boot:run` as the "Command line" value.